# I am getting an error when trying to install requirements.txt in a conda. The error is CondaValueError: could not parse ' ' in: requirements.txt

Tags: anaconda, conda

Here is what I tried

`conda create --name py39 --file requirements.txt`

Here is the error I am getting.
`CondaValueError: could not parse ' ' in: requirements.txt`

Here is the requirements.txt file. for some reason I could not format it correctly here.
https://pastebin.com/RVmd26Us

I tried googling this and can't find anything. Can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: The only solution I could find was to create a environment.yml.